# non-static method getDeviceList() cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android, methods

When running script I receive the error "non-static method getDeviceList() cannot be referenced from a static context" - How do I make this method static?

```
private static String getUsbDeviceAddress(String selection) {
        String address = selection;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 21) {

                HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = UsbManager.getDeviceList();

                for (UsbDevice device : deviceList.values()) {
                    if (device != null) {
                        String dsn = device.getSerialNumber();

                        if ((dsn != null) && !dsn.isEmpty()) {
                            if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase(dsn)) {
                                address = device.getDeviceName();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }

        return address;
    }
```

Comment: you can not call a non-static method  from static method o block so either u could remove static keyword from your  getUsbDeviceAddress() method or create  getDeviceList() static as well

Comment: @vikassingh can you show me how you would create a getDeviceList static?

Answer (score 0):

getDeviceList() method not static.You need to declare like

```
   public static HashMap<String, UsbDevice>  getDeviceList(){}
```